# How to prove sum of squares of scaled consecutive differences converge for a sequence increasing to infinity with consecutive ratio going to 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble proving the following:

Let $a_n \uparrow \infty$ and $a_n/a_{n-1} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Then the sum
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(a_k-a_{k-1})^2}{a_k^2}
\end{equation*}
is finite.

Can someone help me prove it or give a counterexample? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_n=\begin{cases}
1,&n=1\\
{a_{n-1}\over{1-{1\over\sqrt{n}}}}&n>1
\end{cases}$$
Clearly $a_n$ increases and ${a_n\over a_{n_1}}\to1.$  When $n>1,$ we have$$a_n=\prod_{k=2}^n{1\over{1-{1\over\sqrt{k}}}}
=\prod_{k=2}^n{{1+{1\over\sqrt{k}}}\over1-{1\over k}}
=\prod_{k=2}^n{k+\sqrt{k}\over k-1}
=\prod_{k=2}^n\left({1+{1+\sqrt{k}\over k-1}}\right)
$$
Since $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty {1+\sqrt{k}\over k-1}=\infty,$$ we have $a_n\to\infty \text{ as } n\to\infty.$

Now $$\left({a_n-a_{n-1}\over a_n}\right)^2=\left(1-{a_{n-1}\over a_n}\right)^2=\left(1-\left(1-{1\over\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^2={1\over n}$$
so the given series diverges.

Comment: Thanks! I also worked out this example actually!